# Problems with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class Test1{
    JComboBox combo;
    JTextField txt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 b = new Test1();
    }

    public Test1(){
        String degrees[] = {"AAS1","AAS2","AAS1","AAS3"};
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a JComboBox Component");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        combo = new JComboBox(degrees);
        combo.setEditable(true);
        combo.setBackground(Color.gray);
        combo.setForeground(Color.red);

        txt = new JTextField(10);
        txt.setText("1");

        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(txt);
        frame.add(panel);

        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(combo.getSelectedIndex()+1));
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } }
```

As you see from the code above. I have JComboBox with 4 items. If there are no items that are same everything is OK.

But in my example ("AAS1","AAS2","AAS1","AAS3") first and third items are same, and I have problems in this case. 
When I select any item I want to get it's index in JTextField, but when I select third item I get index of first item.
Has any idea?

Comment: Interesting question, but I can't imagine this ever happening outside the classroom.

Comment: I must use this thing in project, can you help me?

Comment: Why are indexes 0 & 2 identical?  How is a user supposed to distinguish between them?

Comment: I don't know, but if I change third item for example to "AAS7" it works normally. It is a bit complicated to explain my application but i need this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because JComboBox is using equals to check the item equality. In your case, those two String are equal so it returns the first index that match. If you really need to do that, you might need to define your own item class like this:

```
private static class MyItem {
    private String value;

    public MyItem(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value; //this is what display in the JComboBox
    }
}
```

And then add the item like this:

```
MyItem degrees[] = {new MyItem("AAS1"),new MyItem("AAS2"),new MyItem("AAS1"),new MyItem("AAS3")};
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(degrees);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class like that:

```
class ComboItem{

    private String name;

    public ComboItem(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and create your combobox:

```
comboBox = new JComboBox(new ComboItem[]{
    new ComboItem("AAS1"),
    new ComboItem("AAS2"),
    new ComboItem("AAS1"),
    new ComboItem("AAS3")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate how the equals is calculated on the `String`s items and the effective representation. I think that this can be done just by creating a specific class for your purpose and use it instead that `String`.

Since this could be homework I'm not going to give exact result, just think about how the `JComboBox` internally chooses the index specified.

Comment: It is not home work I must use this thing in real application. It is only small example that can show what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try using `combo.getSelectedItem()` instead.  Since its two different strings in the String Array, you should be able to do a reference comparison and tell a difference between the two.